# find all the indexes of certain character in string javascript

Tags: javascript

i have certain string

```
const str = "・Welcome to ・StackOverFlow ・Best Regards";
```

i want to get all the indexes of the character **"・"**

unfornately the `indexOf` only gives the first instance

```js
const str = "・Welcome to ・StackOverFlow ・Best Regards";
let bullet_ndx = [];
console.log(str.indexOf("・"));
```

is there a way i could find all the indexes of the certain character?

Comment: If you want a one-liner `bullet_ndx = str.split("").map((c,i)=> c == "・" ? i : -1 ).filter(i => i >= 0 )`

Comment: `bullet_ndx = str.split('').reduce((a, c, i) => c === '・' ? [...a, i] : a, [])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop, and an if condition for this.

```js
const str = "・Welcome to ・StackOverFlow ・Best Regards";

let bulletIndex = []

for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
  if(str[i] == "・"){
    bulletIndex.push(i)
  }
}

console.log(bulletIndex)
```

Comment: i was hoping if there is one function to address this without looping but this is the best possible way.

Comment: @StacksQueue Unfortunately, there is not. There is `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` that gives index of the char starting from forward and backwards respectively. You can write some user defined function though.

Answer (score 0):

indexOf takes a second argument, as a start position to look from

```js
const str = "・Welcome to ・StackOverFlow ・Best Regards";
let bullet_ndx = [];
let index = 0;
while((index = str.indexOf("・", index))>=0) bullet_ndx.push(index++);
console.log(bullet_ndx);
```